# Can't get a string rid of quotes after being converted from array to string

Tags: javascript, replaceall

I have this code:

```js
users = [{
  "userid": "45",
  "name": "steve"
}, {
  "userid": "32",
  "name": "john"
}];

getuser = users.flatMap(user => user.userid === '32' ? user.name : []);

result = getuser.toString();

console.log(result.replaceAll("\"", ""))
```

fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/Ldob8vz2/3/

this should output simple `john` without the quotes but no matter what I do, I can't get rid of those quotes. Why is that?

Comment: um, the quotes is just saying it is a string in the log.

Comment: how do I take them off?

Comment: There are no quotes, it is just how the log shows strings on jsfiddle.

Comment: Don't use `toString()`; use `join(',')`.

Comment: Please use an embedded code snippet instead of linking to a different site. Also, the quotes are just shown by the jsfiddle console and aren't part of the string.

Comment: Thanks, I didnt know jsfiddle did that.

Comment: @skara9 If you don't want to propose the edit yourself, you can at least provide instructions, which are at `https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992` [I've been told to create a "runnable" example with "Stack Snippets", how do I do that?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992)

Comment: JSFiddle doesn't do that, I did.

Comment: Sorry, I thought jsfiddle was okay with this site.

Comment: JSFiddle is fine. @skara9 is overreacting. It is nice to include a runnable snippet via a Stack Snippet, but not required. As long as the code is here on this site as well, someone can make it a snippet if we're feeling generous :).

Comment: Yeah, don't mind it I just came across stronger than I intended.

Comment: Got it. Thank you everybody.

Answer (score -1):

The quotes are an artifact of the way JSFiddle's console displays string values. If you open the browser's native console, you can see that console does not print the quote marks.

Also, the `console` implementation used by Stack Snippets also does not include the quote marks, as demonstrated here (your code without the replace):

```js
users = [{
  "userid": "45",
  "name": "steve"
}, {
  "userid": "32",
  "name": "john"
}];

getuser = users.flatMap(user => user.userid === '32' ? user.name : []);

result = getuser.toString();

console.log(result)
```